# Spring Data Neo4j 4 and primary indexes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to understand how to correctly use primary indexes in SDN 4.

From the `org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Index` javadoc:

```
Only one index per class hierarchy may be marked as primary.
```

Does it mean that if I have a following entity hierarchy:

```
B extends A
C extends A
```

I can't add into the both entities `B` and `C` the following index definition :

```
@Index(unique = true, primary = true)
private Long id;
```

This primary index can be only added to `A` or to `B` or to `C` entity ?

Or if I can add the primary index into the both of them ( `B` and `C`), can `B.id` and `C.id` hold the same value.. for example `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only one index per class hierarchy may be marked as primary.

This means you can have only 1 primary index in a class, or any of its super classes.

E.g. if you have following hierarchy:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
```

you can have only 1 index, in either A, B or C.

In your situation you can have either index in A, or B (or B and C).

The difference is

- if the index is in A, you won't be able to create B and C with same id - constraint on A label will be created
- if the index is in B and C you can create B and C with same id, because it will be 2 separate constraints on 2 separate labels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer